# Should we (or Jeff) create a Facebook page?

Tags: discussion

Once the domain name is decided, should we create a Facebook page to help the site grow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can Facebook pages be renamed? Perhaps I should ask on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ ;)

If so then it should be done sooner rather than later to build up momentum during the beta phase - unless people think there'll be enough traffic from the SO crowd.

I've just noticed that it does say:

> Please note that only the official representative of an organization, business, celebrity, or band is permitted to create a Page.

on [this help page](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=904). So perhaps it does need Jeff or at the very least a diamond mod who could claim to be an "official representative".

Ah - you can't rename pages:

> Once you have claimed a username by clicking the "Confirm" button, it is not possible to edit it, or to transfer your username to a different account on Facebook.

[Source](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=900)

So either we wait for the domain name or create a "beta" page now and then transfer to the "real" one later.

Comment: If we can delete a page Jeff or a Diamond should probably create a beta page now and note that the name will change in the feature, when the time is there we post an update with a link to the new page and remove the page after one or two weeks.